# Use the non-mobile chat interface on iPad

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

My main site is Stack Overflow, where I'm a member of a couple of chat rooms and RO of one of them.

When chatting I'm usually at my iPad, for which I have a keyboard and use the device in "landscape" mode.

Up until this morning (twelve hours ago), chat was shown to me the same as on a PC: with the chat in the left-hand 2/3 of the screen and the room information, users *and menus* to the right. This is important because the tools for Room Owners are in `Room` menu:

[image]

So far, I haven't been able to locate these options in the "mobile" chat view.

In chat preferences for this site I see that apparently a Beta went active overnight that may be the reason my iPad now only shows me the mobile chat view. I see no option, unfortunately, to *turn off* the mobile chat view.

[image]

Am I missing the options in this mobile chat view? If not, is there some way to turn it off, please?

Comment: If you go to the upper left corner while in a chat room there’s a hamburger and one of the options is full site view. Do you have that option?

Comment: @Catija Nothing top-left (I had switched back to the non-Beta interface in the hope it would help). But encouraged by your hint I tried the "full site" link in the old interface and lo-and-behold! THANK YOU. Don't know if this information would be relevant for others? IOW an Answer with the two options?

Comment: I’m sure someone will get to it. I’m on my phone and can’t write it fully but thought I could unstick you in the meantime.

Comment: @Thanks :-) Should I write up the answer, based on the information in comments? I think I could also manage a couple of screen shots...

Comment: If you feel up to it, go for it! Self-answers are great.

Comment: @Catija Done, except I wasn't able to make a screen shot of the menu in the Beta view. I've reactivated it for my profile, but I only get the "old" view. Possibly, the beta is currently disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile view (both beta and current as of October 2019) has an option to display the "full view" that one sees on the PC.

**Current mobile view**

1. At the bottom, left corner of chat, click the `Menu` link.
2. From the menu choose "full site", at the top-right

[image]

**Beta mobile view**

If you go to the upper left corner while in a chat room there’s a hamburger and one of the options is `full site` view.

**To switch to the mobile view**

It's possible to show the mobile view on any device. To switch to the mobile view, go to the very bottom of the chat room and at the far right, click on the `mobile` link.

[image]