# Can't turn off the mobile chat interface in iPad

Tags: support, bug, chat, mobile-web

Back in October [I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335390/use-the-non-mobile-chat-interface-on-ipad) about turning off the mobile chat interface on my iPad. At that time, it was sufficient to choose "full site" from the menu to turn it off.

Sometime over the past few days, something has changed - choosing that menu point no longer has any effect. Everything remains in mobile, which is not useful for me, as a Room Owner.

Can we get this changed so that we can still choose whether to use a mobile interface or not?

Comment: I just came here to meta for the same reason, and saw that you've beaten me to the punch. I suddenly can't access the regular interface any more and it's driving me completely crazy.

Comment: @Ben See the duplicate which has been put on this question. But note it brings up a further problem (bug), to which I'm am currently writing a new question...